# No 'clamp' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGFloat'

Tags: swift, cgfloat

[image]

I explicitly cast the type between them, but the error is still there

```
 var destX:CGFloat  = 5.0

func clamp(value: CGFloat, min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
if value > max {
    return max
}
else if value < min {
    return min
}
return value
}

 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {


let ballRadius: CGFloat = 10
destX = simd.clamp(destX, min: ballRadius, max: frame.width - ballRadius) as CGFloat
let destXAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 0.1)
self.main.run(destXAction)
```

Here is the code

Comment: What type **does** clamp return?

Comment: it returns CGFloat

Comment: Obviously it does **not** otherwise you wouldn't get an error

Comment: how to check it then?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not familiar with this stuff. How about reading the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Having a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/simd_functions), I can't see an overload that takes a CGFloat. `simd.clamp` takes either, `float2`, `float3`, `float4`, `double2`, `double3` or `double4`.

To use **your** `func clamp(value:, min:, max:)`, call it this way :

```
destX = clamp(value: destX, min: ballRadius, max: frame.width - ballRadius)
```

Comment: Use of 'clamp' nearly matches global function 'clamp(_:min:max:)' in module 'simd' rather than instance method 'clamp(value:min:max:)'

Comment: Use 'simd.' to reference the global function in module 'simd'

Comment: @Dakata prefix it with the name of the module you're in or change its name